# Expandable grid Vaadin UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have a simple grid. Two columns with a variable amount of rows. I want to make it so i have a header row with an arrow that can collapse and show the whole grid. So when I bring up the app, only the header row is visible with an arrow, and I can click to expand/collapse to show the rest of the grid.

A [`TreeGrid`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-treegrid.html) seems like overkill since I don’t need any hierarchical structure, just the ability to collapse/expand one row. I exclusively use IE and I’ve read that Drawyer doesnt work with IE 8 and above. I return a list of the objects and the object just has two string variables.

Any help with this? I am new to Vaadin 8.

Comment: Is Spring Boot relevant? If not, delete the tag.

Comment: Please make the effort to type properly. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, not a chat board.

Comment: What is “Drawyer”? A library or add-on? If so, please link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set grid height (workaround)

As a workaround, you could set the height to be approximately the number of pixels you expect to be the height of the header.

See the [Sampler demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features). Click the gear icon at top to expose properties of the example Grid object. The last property shown is "Size (W x H)". Change `100%` to `100px` to see the effect.

### Grid height set to 100%

[image: grid set to 100%]

### Grid height set to 100px

[image: grid set to 100px]

You can also hide the footer (see checkbox in that property list).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Instead of using a button, I’d like to use that icon on the top right of the Sampler demo. Do you know what that is called? I’m having trouble finding it

Comment: @T.Phillips Post another Question for that topic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with plain Vaadin. But I recommend the following simpler approach:

1. Initially call `grid.setHeightByRows(1.5)` ([javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/index.html?com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html)). This will show exactly one row and a half to indicate more data is available. A scrollbar will appear, too.
2. Make a new column within the grid that has a button or add a button below the grid that - when clicked - calls `setHeightByRows` with the number of elements in the grid and hides the button. This will show all rows.